# How to limit Java ServiceLoader to only load service providers defined in test packages

Tags: java, unit-testing, serviceloader

I have an app which uses ServiceLoader.
There is one service interface MyFancyService and its implementations: AppClassA, AppClassB and test implementations: TestClassC, TestClassD 
There is META-INF.services in the app package and another META-INF.services in test package.

> META-INF.services in app point to provider classes AppClassA and
>   AppClassB 
>  META-INF.services in test point to provider classes
>   TestClassC and TestClassD

While running the app, `ServiceLoader.load(MyFancyService.class))` loads only `AppClassA`, `AppClassB`. Obviously there are no test classes in the classpath and that's why. I understand that and it's desirable

While running tests, ServiceLoader.load(MyFancyService.java)) loads all the classes AppClassA, AppClassB, TestClassC, TestClassD.

Is there a way to limit service loader to only load `TestClassC`, `TestClassD` while running tests ?

Comment: Usually test files test the application classes, what will you test without the application?

Comment: Update: After writing an answer I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805688/in-java-how-can-i-mock-a-service-loaded-using-serviceloader

Answer (score 0):

When the test runs it has both "test" and "production" classes/resources in the classpath. 
That's why all four services are loaded and this is a desired behaviour, you obviously need both test and prod classpath.

So, bottom line, you have two options:

**Option 1**

Use tools like PowerMock/PowerMockito that would mock static method `ServiceLoader.load`. I haven't tried this by myself, but in general unless its some sort of legacy code, I don't reacommend to use this.

**Option 2**

Refactor the code and mock the call to service loader as follows:

```
inteface MyServiceLoader {
  void loadMyStuff(Class<?> type);
}

class MyServiceLoaderImpl implements MyServiceLoader {
   public void loadMyStuff(Class<?> type() {
       ServiceLoader.load(type);
   }
}


// and now in ClassUnderTest:

public class ClassUnderTest {

    private MyServiceLoader myServiceLoader;

    public void thisIsAMethodToTest() {
      ...
      myServiceLoader.loadMyStuff(MyFancyInterface.class); 
    }
}
```

In test you can mock the interface `MyServiceLoader.loadMyStuff` with mockito and load only test implementations.

Comment: That's a very good answer but my ServiceLoader.load is hidden behind a custom annotation and executed by static method in one Injector class which resolves annotations. Hard to mock in that case. Maybe I over engineered that a bit. Maybe it's not that harmful to have these app classes being loaded in tests even if there's going to be a huge load of them.

I wanted to achieve something like that in the end:
@ServiceLoad(MyFancyInterface::class)
private lateinit var Iterable< MyFancyInterface >:

Comment: ServiceLoader is a very "low-level" mechanism and doesn't provide such a level of customization...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i.e. my app code has a META-INF/services/my.package.SomeInterface and the unit also has a META-INF/services/my.package.SomeInterface.  It is important for the unit tests to not load the services text file in the app folder, because we call a function someInterface.hasAccess() on all classes returned by the loader, and other teams define their own own implementations and their own hasAccess function, and the unit test errors out unless you properly mock everything, which is an impossible ask.

So I want the test to only see the services text file in the unit test folder.  The classes referenced in this file have an hasAccess function that works without the need for mocking.

For years this was working fine.  But then suddenly the test started picking up the services text file from the app code, and the test started failing.

Looking at the source code for ServiceLoader.java, they load the first resource.  So if the build system changes the class path ordering, you get a different result:

```
                        configs = loader.getResources(fullName);
            ...

            while ((pending == null) || !pending.hasNext()) {
                if (!configs.hasMoreElements()) {
                    return null;
                }
                pending = parse(configs.nextElement());
```

parse(...) always return non-null, so you can see the code picks the first resource in the classpath.

To force it to pick the unit test one, I came up with this solution: Use a context class loader whose getResources method only returns the URL of the file in the test folder.

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        var originalContextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new UnitTestContextClassLoader(originalContextClassLoader));
        try {
            testInternal();
        } finally {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalContextClassLoader);
        }
    }
```

For me originalContextClassLoader is org.powermock2.core.classloader.javassist.JavassistMockClassLoader

The class UnitTestContextClassLoader is:

```
public class UnitTestContextClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    UnitTestContextClassLoader(ClassLoader delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
        var resources = super.getResources(name);
        if (name.equals("META-INF/services/my.package.SomeInterface")) {
            // if running a unit test
            // only return the resource from the test classesfolder or test jar
            // this because ServiceLoader picks the first URL, which may be the wrong one
            List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
            for (var enumeration = resources; enumeration.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                URL url = enumeration.nextElement();
                if (url.toString().contains("test")) {
                    urls.add(url);
                }
            }
            return Collections.enumeration(urls);
        } else {
            return resources;
        }
    }
}
```

Wondering if this is an ok solution.